# Printing groups of array elements in a loop

Tags: c, arrays

Let's assume that I have an array of 6 elements which I want to divide into groups.
Each group should have 3 elements.

I have only this sample code to try and explain what I need to do

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char array[6];


  Group 1: array[0],array[1],array[2]

  Group 2: array[3],array[4],array[5]


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, `Group 1` takes the first three elements of the array, `Group 2` takes the next 3 elements.

I need to do that with a loop, because I actually don't know the number of elements in the array. They could be only 3, or 6 or 9 or 12 and more (but I know that the elements increase by 3, if they actually increase).

So basically I need a loop, which loops through each 3 elements of the array and `printf` them as `Group %d` etc

Comment: Hint: So you know how many "Groups of 3" there are supposed to be. Take a piece of paper and write it out: For Group 0 (start at 0) the indices are....for Group 1....start to see a pattern? That is, how the group number relates to the indices?

Comment: **Moderator Note** _The comments that did not relate to the question at hand were removed, because they degenerated into a pool of noise that was soon to be left even more incoherent due to comment flags. Please keep comments on topic and constructive._

Answer (score 4):

```
assert(length % 3 == 0);
for (int i = 0 ; i < length: i += 3){
    printf("%c %c %c \n", array[i], array[i + 1], array[i + 2]);

}
```

Comment: with an `assert(length%3 == 0)` before

Comment: yes you are right, but the peer specified that the lenght of the array should be a multiple of 3 .

Comment: Which is exactly why an assert is appropriate -- to assure that the requirement is met.